# I don't understand this Javascript comment-like code, can someone clarify this?

Tags: javascript, comments

I am adding some Javascript generated by Google's Adsense on my page, but there is somethong which does not make sense to me:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-1234324234324324";
    /* LeftTop */
    google_ad_slot = "2343454355";
    google_ad_width = 200;
    google_ad_height = 200;
    //-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

Why does Google add `!--` at the beginning of the first script and `//--` at the end? What is the purpose of this code? What does it do? Is it really necessary?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I need to comment the <script> tag in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421599/why-do-i-need-to-comment-the-script-tag-in-html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw this from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/755/JavaScript-For-Beginners):

> Why do we place JavaScript code inside comment fields ? It's for ensuring that the Script is not displayed by old browsers that do not support JavaScript. This is optional, but considered good practice.

Answer (score 2):

It's supposed to make browsers that don't support Javascript ignore everything inside the `<script>` block by making it look like a HTML comment. It's rarely used nowadays.